# WPF binded Listbox bug when display 2 items

Tags: wpf, missing-data

I have a WPF listbox in my window. In the Load event of the window, i create a List(of Object) and I added some items. At application starts or debug, I can see items.
If I add 1 item on the list, i correctly see 1 only item. If I add 3 or more items, i correctly see 3 or more items. If I add 2 only items, i see 1 only item. Why?

Here is my WPF code

```
<Window x:Class="Cacatua.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cacatua;assembly=" >

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="lbSearch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is my code-behind (same assembly, in Cacatua namespace):

```
Private myLstSearch As List(Of Object)

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
     myLstSearch = New List(Of Object)
     lbSearch.ItemsSource = myLstSearch
     Dim myMedia1 as Media1

     myMedia1 = New Media1("IdMedia1-A")
     myLstSearch.Add(myMedia1)

     myMedia1 = New Media1("IdMedia1-B")
     myLstSearch.Add(myMedia1)
End Sub
```

where Media1 is a simple class that contains a string

```
Public Class Media1
    Private myIdTitolo As String
    Public ReadOnly Property IDTitolo As String
        Get
            Return (myIdTitolo)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(str As String)
        myIdTitolo = str
    End Sub
End Class
```

With this code, I would see a list with this output (there is no datatemplate):
    Cacatua.Media1
    Cacatua.Media1

but I see only
    Cacatua.Media1

I think it's a bug. But am I the first with this problem?

Comment: Try setting your `ItemsSource` after you populate the list, and see if that makes a difference. Also, you don't need to both bind the `ItemsSource` property in the XAML and set it in the code-behind. Use only one or the other :)

Comment: Thanks Rachel,
the error was: binding the empty list. I don't know why, but in the Loaded event, if the binding is made AFTER the list addition, i can see also 2 only items!
Misteriously, with a different items number than 2, it works...

Comment: My best guess is a timing issue, although I'm not sure if it would be between when the ItemsControl got rendered, when the ItemsSource got set, or when it attempted to parse the (invalid) binding.

Comment: It's a terrible WPF listbox limitation, and the workaround for resolve this limitation is an horrible overcode... but I have no alternatives!
Thanks another time Rachel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but the problem is your `ItemsSource` doesn't know when to update since you're not using an `ObservableCollection`.  Also there is a timing issue between rendering and loading the window, and I think this has to do with the fact you aren't properly binding your items source.

For starters, try changing the type of `myLstSearch` to `ObservableCollection(Of Media1)`.

Also, a better way to do this would be to databind it from the XAML directly, so your code-behind would be something like:

```
Public property MyListSearch As ObservableCollection(Of Media1)
```

Then your XAML would look like:

```
<Window x:Class="Cacatua.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cacatua;assembly=">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="lbSearch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListSearch}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

That way, you can simply initialize `MyListSearch` in your window constructor, and then add elements to it whenever, while your view will automatically update.